# oracle 11g: increasing buffer cache with AMM

Tags: oracle, memory

On a 2-node RAC we have enabled Automatic Memory Management. The advisor views indicate that increasing the buffer cache by 4G will halve the physical reads, and we have 4G to give. How must we do this? By increasing memory_target and letting Oracle grab more memory for the buffer cache? Or by explicitly setting a value for db_cache_size (which now is zero)?